# How to avoid polkit error/timeout "Authorization not available" when restarting systemd services as root

Tags: systemd, d-bus, polkit

On a very small server I have `polkit` and `dbus` daemons/services not running in order to save resources and harden the server (these are not needed for normal running and they increase the attack surface dramatically).  As a result, when I restart a service/daemon I get a warning/error message, e.g.

```
# systemctl restart named.service
Authorization not available. Check if polkit service is running or see debug message for more information.
```

The process hangs in the foreground (I think the usual `systemd` timeout of 90 seconds), then exits.

The `systemctl` command (here, restarting bind) does work!  However, the contacting of `polkitd` via `dbus` (or what else is it?) to check whether root may in fact restart `bind` (which would obviously return true) takes 90s to timeout.

So: **Is there a way to remove this polkit check** as it works anyway (I am root!)?

PS: Please do not suggest to enable+start `dbus` and `polkit` services as a fix because the question is how to disable the check. I am no running them for a reason.

Comment: I'm curious, if you use `sudo` to invoke that (even as root), is it enough to skip the `polkit` check?